# Group Dates to corresponding months and sum hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

On Sql Server 2012 (T-SQL), I would like to analyse a list of absence dates and rearrange the data to summarise information, catalogued by month.

Example:

Here is a list of raw data

```
  TimeSheetID UserID   LeaveID    StartDate      EndDate      Duration
      1        779      1        01/01/2016    01/01/2016     7.5
      2        779      1        02/01/2016    02/01/2016     7.5
      3        779      2        03/01/2016    03/01/2016     7.5  
      4        1021     3        01/01/2016    02/01/2016     7.5
      5        999      4        30/01/2016    30/01/2016     7.5
      6        999      4        31/01/2016    31/01/2016     7.5
      7        999      4        01/02/2016    01/02/2016     7.5
      8        999      4        02/02/2016    02/02/2016     7.5
      9        123      5        27/02/2016    28/02/2016     12
      10       123      5        29/02/2016    01/03/2016     12
      11       123      5        01/03/2016    02/03/2016     12
```

Below is the preferred output, you can see that in most cases the data is summarised, however where dates lapse into a new month the data is segregated into a new month group.

Equally where the date range lapses over a two day period this is classed as a night shift thus the start date is taken as the grouping factor and in to the corresponding month grouping.

```
   UserID    LeaveID   StartDate      EndDate      Duration
     779       1       01/01/2016    02/01/2016      15 
     779       2       03/01/2016    03/01/2016      7.5
    1021       3       01/01/2016    02/01/2016      7.5
     999       4       30/01/2016    31/01/2016      15
     999       4       01/01/2016    02/02/2016      15
     123       5       27/02/2016    01/03/2016      24
     123       5       01/03/2016    02/03/2016      12
```

Comment: I don't get it.  How is `LeaveId` 1 collapsed to one row but not `LeaveId` 5?

Comment: Source table line `123      5        01/02/2016    02/03/2016     12` is that correct  or typo?

Comment: `Leave Id`  5 cant collapse to 1 row as one period of its absence starts in a new month

Comment: Just to be clear, are we talking Islands and Gaps?

Comment: @ Searching sorry yes a typo I have corrected this

Comment: @John Cappelletti I have amended the table example. Does this help? It can be the case that the leaveID is scattered across the table rather than being in a grouped approach

Comment: Isn't this just a simple group by statement? e.g. `SELECT UserID, LeaveID, MIN(StartDate), MAX(EndDate), SUM(Duration) FROM myTable GROUP BY UserID, LeaveID, DATEPART(MONTH, StartDate) ORDER BY LeaveID;`

Comment: @zlk's comment is correct but it looks like that StartDate is a varchar and you'll probably want it as a date `select convert(date,StartDate,103)`

Comment: @scsimon or just `DATEFORMAT DMY;` should work.

Comment: Ah yes @ZLK I missed the 2012 tag. FORMAT() would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I have a disconnect on your last two values.  (Highlighted below)

```
Select UserID
      ,LeaveID
      ,StartDate = Min(KeyDate)
      ,EndDate   = Max(KeyDate)
      ,Duration  = cast(Sum(PerDay) as decimal(10,2))
 From  (Select KeyDate=RetVal From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]((Select min(StartDate) from @YourTable),(Select max(EndDate) from @YourTable),'DD',1) ) A
 Join  (Select *,PerDay = Duration/(1+DateDiff(DD,StartDate,EndDate)) From @YourTable) B on (A.KeyDate Between B.StartDate and B.EndDate)
 Group By 
       UserID
      ,LeaveID
      ,Month(KeyDate)
 Order By LeaveID
```

Returns

[image]

Now, I use a TVF to create dynamic Date Ranges, but a Tally/Calendar Table will do the trick as well.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Now if you are NOT spreading duration across months

```
Select UserID
      ,LeaveID
      ,StartDate = Min(StartDate)
      ,EndDate   = Max(EndDate)
      ,Duration  = sum(Duration)
 From @YourTable
 Group By 
       UserID
      ,LeaveID
      ,Month(StartDate)
 Order By LeaveID
```

Returns

[image]